# GRUB problem after creating new partition - not able to boot live-cd

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue, cd

I've created a new NTFS partition under windows - after reebooting I've received the following error:
Unknown file system
Entering rescue mode
Grub rescue >

I would've booted one of my ubuntu live cds, but it won't even boot any of those, it hows an idle underscore blinking, and after a while the CD stops running. Tried this with 3 different ubuntu live-cds, the system refuses to boot any distribution.
Does anyone knows how to resolve this?
I'm not able to format my hard disk, even if I wanted to :(

Comment: Did you create new partition with Windows? Windows usually 'forgets' to rewrite partition table with the Linux partition. Often testdisk can easily restore the missing partition. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk Also post this: It should show missing or unallocated space where Linux partition was: sudo parted -l

Comment: Easiest way is to boot from livecd and reinstall grub. Repartitioning your hard drive will not stop you booting a CDROM or USB drive. So there must be another reason, do you have Secure Boot or Fast Boot enabled in the BIOS?